# Can POST request be an alternative to GET request in most of the scenarios?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, http-post, httprequest, http-get

I wet thru http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp and wondered why should i not always prefer
POST request over GET request. I can think of two scnarios where i have to use POST request instead of GET
Request. These are:-

> 1)Where i have requirement to bookmark the the URL
>
> 2)Where my requirement is to cache the web page (as POST request does
>   not cache the web page), so that next time same url is hit it can be
>   obtained from cache and optimize the performance.

I agree POST request is designed to create/update the resource where GET request is designed
to retrieve the resource.Though,techincally they can be used vice versa also.

**So i was wondering
is it not always benefecial to use POST request over GET request(except the two requirements i mentioned
above) as Post is more secure?** Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes. you are right. In POST request, users can't see what parameters you are sending. you can avoid URL injection. and you also correct abt the GET request to make bookmark and to cache the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons to use HTTP the way it was meant to be used. Here's a couple:

- The value of the web is built on URLs. Every time you provide a page which is obtainable only via POST, you are denying the option to *link to it*, as well as to bookmark it. (Obviously a form button can still be made, but that's not as convenient.) Even if the page is some kind of “service”, there is still often value in linking — that you won't have thought of beforehand.
- If the user reloads a page obtained via POST, most web browsers will warn that they are “resubmitting a form” and confirm the action. This is because in poorly designed applications this can result in things like placing a duplicate order or posting a duplicate message. Therefore, using GET for requests which **do not have side effects** eliminates this unnecessary warning. In fact, a useful practice for POSTs which have effects is to make the response to them be a redirect to a URL (which the browser will GET) for a page *describing the results of the action* (for example, if the POST posted a comment, it would then redirect to a link to the comment); this way the page can be reloaded (which could be implicit e.g. if the browser were restarted) without any ambiguity about whether it's re-executing the action.